# Android Custom ActionBar doesn't show NavigationDrawer's icon in some devices

Tags: android, android-layout

For my app I'm using a menu that is a NavigationDrawer and it's working perfectly. At this moment I have created my custom layout of action bar, just with the propose to have an icon centered in actionbar.
The problem is that apparently in some devices the NavigationDrawer's icon isn't showing with my custom ActionBar layout, but it's showing if I don't apply my custom ActionBar layout.
On my android 4.4.2 it's working fine. I've tried on 4.1.2 and on 4.3 and the icon not showing.

Here is my ActionBar layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ActionBarWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_centered_icon"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here you have the lines on my Activity that set my custom layout for the action bar and also the code that implements the navigationDrawer:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_centered_icon);
    ImageView actionBarCenteredIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_centered_icon);
    actionBarCenteredIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.vidytape_text);

    // Hide App icon
    // getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    // Enable user to open menu from the button on action bar
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // Remove app title from action bar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Set menu ic drawer as icon
    /*
     * if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase("deutsch")){
     * getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.label_home_de); } else {
     */
    getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.vidytape_text);
    // }

    ColorDrawable actionBarColor = new ColorDrawable(
            Color.parseColor("#3498db"));
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(actionBarColor);

    // Menu behavior -- Toggle
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle((Activity) this,
            mDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()

            //Close keyboard
            viewsSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.views_search);
            nicesSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nices_search);
            newestSearchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newest_search);

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(viewsSearchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(nicesSearchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(newestSearchField.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }; // End of menu behavior

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```

Anyone know what can be the problem here?

**I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

To make it work on the SDKs < 19 and on 19 too, I added the following two lines of code:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    ColorDrawable actionBarIconColor = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    getActionBar().setIcon(actionBarIconColor);
```